# Laravel scope filtering, whereJsonContains not working

Tags: mysql, json, laravel, laravel-7

my project is Laravel 7+ and MySql
I have a 'villas' table in which there is a column named 'amenities' with JSON data type format.
and each 'amenity' may/or/may not have sub category.
I store each villa's list of amenities(and their sub-amenities) as an JSON format like
`{"1":["24","30"],"3":[],"4":[],"7":[],"8":[],"9":["9"],"11":["28","29"],"12":[]}`

in my Controller

```
        if(request()->am){
         ///// $request->am is a series of input checkboxes and is returned as an Array
            $villas->filterAmenity($request->am);
        }
```

and in my **Villa**  model

```
///// DID NOT WORK ///
            $q->whereJsonContains('amenities',$filterAM[0])->orWhereJsonContains(function($qu){
                for($i = 1; $i <= count($filterAM) - 1; $i++) {
                    $qu->orWhereJsonContains('amenities', $filterAM[$i]);
                }
            });

////////////=======================//////////////

///// DID NOT WORK ///
    public function scopeFilterAmenity($q,$filterAM){
        $q->whereJsonContains('amenities',['3']);
    }
///// DID NOT WORK ///
```

ANY help and suggestion is highly appreciated. thanks in advance

Comment: maybe a stupid question. The database field is json or text or whatever?

Comment: Are you trying to query the key or the value in the json ? Because there is also a `whereJsonContainsKey` method.

Comment: @Jack I set Database to JSON , however it changed it to longtext ..

Comment: @RamyHerrira {"1":["24","30"],"3":[],"4":[],"7":[],"8":[],"9":["9"],"11":["28","29"],"12":[]}  this is what is stored in database, main amenities, and their possible sub-amenity.  I think I should look for JSON , not JSON key .. right ?